# Знаки препинания в сложных предложениях

Tags: пунктуация

Прошло 50 лет (,) и прямо как у Пушкина: «Прошло сто лет, и юный град, полночных стран краса и диво... вознесся пышно, горделиво» (далее предложение продолжается)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли сомнительная запятая?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В качестве варианта:

Прошло 50 лет ―   **и почти** как у Пушкина:  "...**юный град, полночных стран краса и диво... вознесся пышно, горделиво**».

Вместо тире можно поставить запятую, также желательно знать продолжение. Чтобы редактировать такое предложение, его структуру надо видеть полностью, так как стихотворный текст может просто не вписаться в прозаический.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!